# specify pom.xml in mvn command and mix goals of other project

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

I have multiple questions.

1. Can I specify the pom.xml in mvn command?
2. Can I mix the goals of another project while executing mvn command on current project ?

   **Eg: mvn clean-otherproject comple-otherproject instal-otherproject compile-thisproject**

I can do this with multiple mvn commands, but Can I do this in single maven command.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Just `mvn --help` would have answered the first question:

```
 mvn -f otherPomFile.xml
```

No. You can simple execute the phases for the current project you are in. You can give multiple phases like

```
mvn clean install site site:deploy
```

Comment: `mvn --help` may have been useful, but Google quickly led me to your answer for just the first bit (thanks)

Comment: -f is most important in this

Answer (score 5):

For the first question, see [khmarbaise's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023597/specify-pom-xml-in-mvn-command-and-mix-goals-of-other-project/4023629#4023629)

---

If you want to build more than one maven project in one step, you must use [modules](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation).

In a multi-module project, if you call `mvn install` from the top project, all sub modules are built, unless you use the [advanced reactor options](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/) (e.g. `mvn install -pl util -am` only builds the module 'util' and it's dependencies)