# multi artifact id in one pom

Tags: maven, maven-jar-plugin

There is a maven  project(jar), but now it needs to be spilt into two artifacts

I want to have two maven artifact like following

```
<groupId>xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>xxx-client</groupId>

<groupId>xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>xxx-impl</groupId>
```

But all the code is in one single project.

> My question would be, How can I package the tow required artifacts without changing the project too much.

Then ,

> mvn package deploy

will auto deploy these two artifacts into repository
Actually I don't want to split these project into two maven project.

Comment: It would be nice if you can post your pom to give better suggestion how to solve your problem and in particular to understand your problem at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a possibility of having two `<artifactId>` tags in one POM, since it is unique. What you may do is, you can have two pom files, say, `pom.xml`, and `pom_impl.xml`, now

- to deploy client do, `mvn package deploy`
- to deploy impl do, `mvn -f pom_impl.xml package deploy`

Never tried though.

---

*Clarification*: The question seem ambiguous, seems like you have one project but you wanted to generated two artifacts (client, and impl) of the same code-base. On reading it again, I feel like you have two projects (two different code base) but you just wanted to unify it so that it behaves as two modules of the same project. My answer assumes the first case.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correct, you need to have a super pom (xxx/pom.xml) and two different poms for both of your projects (xxx-client and xxx-impl). The structure of your super pom will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>xxx-client</module>
        <module>xxx-impl</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Then when you deploy your main pom, it will deploy it's modules as well.

Here are references if you want to read more about [super pom](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance) and [modules](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is called "multi module project" in the Maven world. You can find information on how to do this e.g. [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html). Indeed you need two separate POMs and an additional one to combine both.

Answer (score 0):

[specify pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023597/specify-pom-xml-in-mvn-command-and-mix-goals-of-other-project)

Make two pom ,then specify the pom in command line, that is the easiest way.