# maven with multiple artifactID

Tags: java, maven

I need to build different type of **library** which differ only in manifest information.

It is not a good idea to make different projects since sources are exactly the same.

I tried module pom, but the child pom can not reference to the parent source.

I also tried `artifactId` with property(eg: `libarayname-${type}`), but it doesn't look right.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/9075259/2006839

Comment: putting another pom in the same directory should work, I think. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin)

Use two different assembly descriptors, and you will also be able to specify different MANIFEST files. See the [plugin usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) for more info.

You two libraries can then be generated with different classifiers, so that other project can depend on any.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the MANIFEST.MF by configuring the [maven archiver plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/manifest-customization.html)

A "brute force" approach to what you're trying to achieve is to create a maven profile for each variation of MANIFEST.MF that you need.

Comment: The problem is that artifactID is the same. When I run deploy, the jars will upload to the same artifactID in repository.

Comment: True. I didn't think of that. In that case, the suggestion to use multiple pom-files sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

What you should actually use is a classifier. Check the `maven-jar-plugin` for more info on how to produce more than one artifacts from a single project. For example, if the project is called `foo`, then you can have `foo-1.2.3` and `foo-1.2.3-jdk14`, or something along those lines.