# Create an artifact alias without copying the full project module

Tags: java, maven, alias, artifact

In my maven project, I am looking for a way to create an artifact alias for an artifact that I have created. The reason is that a specific artifact used to be deployed under with a different artifactId and I want to keep supporting this old artifactId for the time being, even for new releases, without having to have a full duplicate module for this other artifact.

For example. Say I have the artifact `foo-bar` in version 1.0 of my project and I decided to rename this artifact to `foo-baz` in version 2.0, but I still want to support the `foo-bar` artifactId until the release of version 3.0, for backwards compatibility reasons.

So therefore I want to find a way to define `foo-bar` as an alias for `foo-baz`. Is this possible to do?

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075259/multi-artifact-id-in-one-pom you can generate 2 artifacts using 2 poms in a single project

Comment: Ok that would indeed work well for a single module project. Would I also be able to specify this second artifact to be automatically built when I build the super pom in a multi-module project? Or would that cause problems because the pom file has a different name?

Comment: This is called a [relocation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-relocation.html) but If I correctly remember you can't relocate an artifactId you can only relocate an groupId...Apart from that I would announce that change with the current 2.X releases and then simply change the artifactId for the first 3.X release. The decision to rename an artifact is a breaking change which in itself is a reason to make major version change..which you seemed to miss...

Comment: Could you add the relocation as an answer @khmarbaise with an example from the link? That way future people who stumble onto this problem can see the answer immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [relocation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-relocation.html) but If I correctly remember you can't relocate an artifactId you can only relocate an groupId...Apart from that I would announce that change with the current 2.X releases and then simply change the artifactId for the first 3.X release. The decision to rename an artifact is a breaking change which in itself is a reason to make major version change..which you seemed to miss...