# How to run mvn clean install from another directory?

Tags: java, maven

I have java application and deployed in a folder A. But I want to run **mvn commands(mvn clean install)** from folder B. Is that possible?

Comment: See the https://stackoverflow.com/a/4023629/3793078. using -f option (`mvn -f ../B/pom.xml`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Maven from another directory (without cd to project dir)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478536/how-to-run-maven-from-another-directory-without-cd-to-project-dir)

Comment: Is it a multi maven structure?

Answer (score 8):

Use the parameter -f then specify the path to your pom file, 
for example  : 
mvn -f /path/to/pom.xml

This runs maven for the working directory.

Comment: This works for me. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you want to build multiple projects, you can create a xml file like below and then use `mvn clean install`

`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>full-build</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>My Project Name</name>
    <description>Full build of the Projects.</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>path of module 1</module>
        <module>path of module 2</module>
        <!-- You can even use relative path -->
        <module>../folder1/relativePath/module 3</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencies>
        // if any
    </dependencies>
</project>`